# Using while loop for user entry until Enter is pressed

Tags: list, python-3.x, while-loop

I have a list of floats (L1) and I want to create L2, which is L1 * a. I want the user to see the plot of L1 and L2 to see if he is happy with the 'a' he entered. He can enter a different 'a' until he is happy with the plot and then hit Enter to end the while loop. I have tried the below, but my code only graphs when I hit enter (and not every time a new a is entered). What am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
L1 = [10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 13.4, 14.5, 13.4, 12.3, 11.1, 10.0]
done = False        
while not done:
    a = float(input("Please enter alpha (between 0 and 1), Enter to exit: "))
    L2 = [x * a for x in L1]
    plt.plot(L1)
    plt.plot(L2)
    if a == "":
        done = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are coercing the input to `float`

```
a = float(input("Please enter alpha (between 0 and 1), Enter to exit: "))
```

And here you are checking if that `float` is an empty `string` (which it can't be)

```
if a == "":
    done = True
```

I would suggest

```
while not done:
    a = input("Please enter alpha (between 0 and 1), Enter to exit:")
    if a == "":
        done = True
    else:
        a = float(a)
        L2 = [x * a for x in L1]
        plt.plot(L1)
        plt.plot(L2)
```

Comment: Although you rightfully pointed out mistakes in my code, which I appreciate, it is still not behaving like I wanted it to. The code is still looping asking for 'a' and the graph only comes after I hit Enter..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? With the above code, when you only hit enter, it will exit. When you type a `float` and hit enter, it will call the `plot` methods and ask for another number.

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
L1 = [10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 13.4, 14.5, 13.4, 12.3, 11.1, 10.0]
done = False
while not done:
    a = input("Please enter alpha (between 0 and 1), Enter to exit:")
    if a == "":
        done = True
    else:
        a = float(a)
        L2 = [x * a for x in L1]
        plt.plot(L1)
        plt.plot(L2)

Please enter alpha (between 0 and 1), Enter to exit:0.7

Please enter alpha (between 0 and 1), Enter to exit:

Comment: Does not work my end.. It keeps asking for a float and plots nothing.. Not until I hit Enter comes the plot.

Comment: Just tested it. Works as expected on Python3, and almost as expected on Python2 (exits as expected, but with an error) and outputs and loops as expected. Are you sure you copied the above correctly?

Comment: Before your code I have my first three lines, is that right? I'm using Python 3 and Spyder 2.